# Spring Boot how to query for five items with different conditions without multiple queries

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have this entity:

```
public class Notification extends BaseEntity implements INotification {

    @NotNull
    private NotificationType type;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private SchoolSubject subject;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Student creator;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student lastEditedBy;

    private LocalDateTime lastEditedAt = LocalDateTime.now();

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Student> checkedBy;

    @ManyToOne
    private StudyGroup studyGroup;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    private String description;

    private LocalDate date;

}
```

I would like to get the first 5 notifications for each day from a given range. (for example 18.4.2022 to 25.4.2022)
How can I do this, without writing multiple queries? Or if there is no other option than writing multiple queries, how efficient would that be?
Thanks.

Comment: `select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by date(dt) order by dt) as rn from t where dt between '2022-04-18' and '2022-04-25') x where rn <= 5` ?

Comment: Thanks, I would never be able to create such a complex query (complex at least for my standards). When I get the chance, I will try to use it in my app and if it works, I'll definitely upvote your comment :)